# c# how to sort array after what I want?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

How do I sort an array after the elements I want to sort them after?
This is my code so far:

```
public override byte[] SaveSettings()
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.AppendLine(@"#Smurf bot");
    object[] keys = new object[GetKeys().Count];
    GetKeys().CopyTo(keys, 0);
    var keysSorted = keys.OrderBy(x => x);
    foreach (string key in keysSorted)
    {
        builder.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}\n", key, GetValue(key));
    }
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(builder.ToString());
}
```

This is how it's being sorted now:

[image: unsorted list]

But I want it so get sorted like, Rcs Enabled, Rcs Start After, Rcs Force Max, Rcs Force Min and so son...

As you can see right now I use `OrderBy` Also tried with `OrderByDesencding`
But it dosen't order the list they way I want to order it. Can I somehow hard code how I want to sort the array?

Comment: How *do you* want to order the list?

Comment: How exactly *do* you want it ordered??

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: so you want to sort string array `keys`. have you tried `Array.Sort(keys);` note that return type of `Sort` is void and the the array `keys` will be updated.

Comment: You can use `var keysSorted = keys.OrderBy(x => x.toString());` assuming you want it sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Thats the answer i think! i didnt notice `x` is type of object. @JaimeTorres

Answer (score 0):

> But I want it so get sorted like, Rcs Enabled, Rcs Start After, Rcs Force Max, Rcs Force Min and so son...

That sounds like you have some arbitrary order in mind by which you want the entries to appear. Built-in methods like LINQ’s OrderBy, or even a normal List.Sort will only help you, as long as you have some actual definition of the order.

So if you don’t have an order in mind which can be determined by looking at the value (i.e. sorting it by alphabet, or having a common pattern which you can utilize), then your only chance is to implement the order completely yourself.

You have multiple ways to do that:

1. You could create a mapping from an entry to a number where the number reflects the position in the ordered sequence. For example, make a dictionary where you map each possible word to a number:

   ```
   Dictionary<string, int> mapping = new Dictionary<string, int>()
   {
       { "Rcs Enabled", 0 },
       { "Rcs Start After", 1 },
       { "Rcs Force Max", 2 },
       { "Rcs Force Min", 3 }
       …
   };
   ```

   You can then use that mapping in the `OrderBy`:

   ```
   keys.OrderBy(k => mapping[k]);
   ```
2. You could also create a simple list that is exactly ordered as you like. And then, you just compare the sorted complete list with your `keys` list. And you filter out those values that are not in your `keys` list. That way, you start with a fully sorted list of all values, and end up with the same values from `keys` but keeping the order:

   ```
   List<string> allKeysSorted = new List<string>()
   {
       "Rcs Enabled", "Rcs Start After", "Rcs Force Max", "Rcs Force Min",
       …
   };

   var sortedKeys = allKeysSorted.Where(k => keys.Contains(k));
   ```

There are probably other solutions, but unless you have some kind of automatic way to determine the order between two arbitrary keys, you will have to define it explicitly in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SortedDictionary class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This sorts a dictionary by key. You can sort by a custom order using a custom IComparer in the constructor.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a045f865%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an order.  Use a class like the code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Setting> settings = new List<Setting>() {
                new Setting() { name = "Trigger Burst Enabled", order = 1},
                new Setting() { name = "Rcs Start After", order = 2},
                new Setting() { name = "Trigger RCS", order = 4},
                new Setting() { name = "Trigger Burst Shots", order = 5},
                new Setting() { name = "Trigger Key", order = 7},
                new Setting() { name = "Rcs Force Max", order = 4},
                new Setting() { name = "Trigger Toggle", order = 3},
                new Setting() { name = "Trigger Delay FirstShot", order = 4},
                new Setting() { name = "Rcs Enabled", order = 5},
                new Setting() { name = "Trigger Allies", order = 6},
                new Setting() { name = "Trigger Enemies", order = 7},
                new Setting() { name = "Trigger Enabled", order = 8},
                new Setting() { name = "Rcs Force Min", order = 6},
                new Setting() { name = "Trigger Hold", order = 3},
                new Setting() { name = "Trigger Delay Shots", order = 4}
            };

            List<string> names = settings.OrderBy(x => x.order).Select(y => y.name).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Setting
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int order { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```